# How to write a function to output unconstant loop

Tags: php, loops, recursion

Here is the function description

```
test($argv)
```

`$argv` is an array, for example `$argv=array($from1,$to1,$from2,$to2.....);`
array items must be even.

`$argv=array(1,3,4,5)` : this will output values like below:

```
1_4
1_5
2_4
2_5
3_4
3_5
```

pseudocode is like

```
while($from1<=$to1){
   while($from2<=$to2){
         echo $from1."_".$from2."<br/>";
        $from2++;
   }
   $from1++;
}
```

`$argv=array(1,2,3,4,5,6)` : this will output values like below:

```
1_3_5
1_3_6
1_4_5
1_4_6
2_3_5
2_3_6
2_4_5
2_4_6
```

pseudocode is like

```
while($from1<=$to1){
   while($from2<=$to2){
        while($from3<=$to3){
             echo $from1."_".$from2."_".$from3."<br/>";
             $from3++;
        }
        $from2++;
   }
   $from1++;
}
```

The number of array $argv's is not constant.
Maybe 3 or 4 levels of loop will be outputed.

i just heard that tail recuision or iteration will be used, but i don't know exactly how to code.

Comment: Could you generalize what this function is supposed to do? AFAIU it should output every possible combination of `$from` values and `$to` values..?

Comment: @deceze question has been edited to discript more accurate.

Comment: Sorry, that's even less clear. Why is there a `2` output in the first example, there's no `2` in the input? Please just try to put the logic into words, that'll help you as well.

Comment: @deceze: +1 for that last sentence. It appears that each 'from','to' pair represents a range of values between 'from' and 'to' (inclusive)

Comment: @wallacoloo yes,that's what i mean.(english is hard,囧)

Comment: Doing this recursive is way harder then iterative ... why do you need it recursive?

Comment: Sooo... every odd/even input pair represents a range of numbers, and you want to output all possible combinations of every number in every range with every other number in every other range?

Comment: @Buttink other method also ok only of this can function good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below function should do what you want. It doesn't print the result but instead returns an array with the results that you can iterate over and print it.

```
$testArray = array('1', '3', '4', '5');
$testArray2 = array('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6');

function test($a) {
  $from1 = array_shift($a);
  $to1 = array_shift($a);

  $result = array();

  while ($from1 <= $to1) {
    if (sizeof($a) > 0) {
      $rest = test($a);
      foreach ($rest as $b) {
        $result[] = $from1.'_'.$b;
      }

    } else {
      $result[] = $from1;
    }
    $from1++;
  }
  return $result;
}

print_r(test($testArray));
print_r(test($testArray2));
```

As an advice read up on recursion as it's an extremely useful technique. It's sometimes hard to wrap your head around it but it's well worth the effort. [This book](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) from MIT has a great chapter on recursion if i remember correctly, and its free. Have  fun.

Comment: fixed it to do the proper thing (I hope).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some functions:

```
    header("Content-type: text/plain");

    function testFromTo($args) {
        echo "***** testFromTo *****\n";
        // uses indexes parity to walk the array
        foreach ($args as $k1=>$v1) {
            if (($k1 + 1) % 2 == 1) {
                foreach ($args as $k2=>$v2) {
                    if (($k2 + 1) % 2 == 0) {
                        echo $v1 . "_" . $v2 . "\n";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function testHalf($args) {
        echo "***** testHalf *****\n";
        // cuts $args in two parts
        $args1 = array_slice($args, 0, count($args) / 2);
        $args2 = array_slice($args, count($args) / 2);

        foreach ($args1 as $v1) {
            foreach ($args2 as $v2) {
                echo $v1 . "_" . $v2 . "\n";
            }
        }
    }


    $argv = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
    testFromTo($argv);
    testHalf($argv);

    exit;
?>
```

and associated outputs:

```
***** testFromTo *****
1_2
1_4
1_6
3_2
3_4
3_6
5_2
5_4
5_6
***** testHalf *****
1_4
1_5
1_6
2_4
2_5
2_6
3_4
3_5
3_6
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
test("1", "2", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");

function test(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $cnt = func_num_args();
    //echo "cnt :: " . ($cnt % 2) . "\n";

    if(($cnt % 2) > 0) return false;

    $split = $cnt / 2;
    list($list1, $list2) = array_chunk($args, ($cnt / 2));
foreach($list1 as $idx=>$val){
    foreach($list2 as $idx2=>$val2){
        echo $list1[$idx] . "_" . $list2[$idx] . "\n";
    }
}       
}
```

Here's the output:

```
1_6
1_6
1_6
1_6
2_7
2_7
2_7
2_7
4_8
4_8
4_8
4_8
5_9
5_9
5_9
5_9
```

Comment: @silent no,not like this,dude.
recursive must be used to output what i need.

Comment: @tunpishuang Why do you insist on recursion? The best you could do here is tail recursion, which is the same as a loop.

Comment: I think this is from school task.